# Application Insights - No data showing up from server

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-application-insights

This is a tough question to ask... so I'll try to describe the contours of the situation as best I can:

I have a WCF service that uses the AI Console implementation I've followed from:
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console/

Sample code:

```
            string applicationInsightsConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"];
            TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            configuration.ConnectionString = applicationInsightsConnectionString;
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
```

The global.asax calls `telemetryClient.TrackTrace("application start");` on app start and this is the simplest example of what I wish to see in AI.

When running this code locally through visual studio and giving it 30 seconds to flush I get a result in AI:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Sadly when I deploy this code to the server to run in IIS I do not get any records to show up in AI.

What puzzles me even more is that this is the 3rd implementation I've done in the exact same way (all WCF services running in IIS), yet this is the only one that does not record any results in the azure portal eventhough it works locally.

I've triple checked the web.config if it has the correct connectionstring and I've added test code to check if the calls succeed by writing simple test lines to the database... everything seems fine.

Any idea's what else I can check to get this to work? I am kind of stuck as I can not think of a next action to get to a solution.

Many thanks, Davey

Comment: Are they all using the same connection string/same AppInsights server?

Comment: can you dump the connection string that you're retrieving from web.config to console or a text file? Just to be sure it's actually looking in web.config and not another config settings implementation?

Comment: Also, I find it takes something like 5 minutes to fully flush to Appinsights, but that may be a function of my environment!

Comment: You could compare the differences between the three implementations, such as ConnectionString,etc. You can also look for the IIS and WCF running logs, and you may find some results.

Comment: @AnnL. I've written the connectionstring to a database log table, and compared them with what I expected. They are the same :(

Comment: @AnnL. I've also attempted some test code where I added a .flush directly after the trace and then Thread.Sleep(5000).

And it has been more than a few days since my first test so those 5 minutes have past :/

Comment: @Jiayao I've actually (just for my own sanity) implemented this AI implementation again from scratch based on the previous implementation that worked. Sadly no result.

IIS logs and windows event viewer sadly to don't show any faults or exceptions occurring

Comment: All these apps (the successful and the unsuccessful) are all running on the same IIS server?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes that is whats making me so confused

Comment: @AnnL. I've added some more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging with WireShark I found that the calls to applications insights were in TSL1.0, not TSL1.2 and therefore not accepted.

After adding

```
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        }
```

To the global.asax.cs

The calls were in TSL1.2 and they arrived in azure :)

(Adding the following to the web.config also works)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
</system.web>
```